# why does occurs this error :"undefined symbol:_i2c_port" in codevision AVR compiler?

Tags: c, assembly, compilation, avr, i2c

I want to drive a si4734_D60 as a FM receiver by atmega8 through I2C. After compiling the code by'codevision AVR 3.12 advanced', No error occurs in "C" code but at last this error is displayed:
"Error(s) occurred during assembly" and someof errors are:
Error: C:\Users...\SI4734_receiver.asm(2346): Undefined symbol: __i2c_port
that assembly code in line 2346 is:

```
    .equ __i2c_dir=__i2c_port-1
```

and you can find my project here:
[googledrive:Si4734.rar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F9AXpy8HZhhnFJtqjZmjHpi1bZD6is-W/view?usp=sharing)

I don't understand these errors. please help me about it.

Comment: Apparently the assembler doesn't know the symbol `__i2c_port`. Please [edit] your question and include a [mre] in the question instead of providing an archive with sources. Show the source code and the commands that are executed to compile it.

Comment: I tried to coding in form of OOP, so I have to share my project.

Comment: Most if not all users here refuse to copy your complete project just to reproduce and investigate your issue. Please save us all the time to minimize your program and do it yourself as part of the debugging process. Remove things step by step and check each time that the issue still exists. When you are down to the minimum, copy the source complete and verbatim into your question.

Comment: @sajad so you decided to post the whole project and we should debug it for free!!! I want too. Guys I will post my work project - please finish it and I meanwhile will go on  holiday

Comment: @sajad – Where and how do you think `__i2c_port` is defined?

Comment: No No No it does not need any debug. It is a misunderstanding. I just share my project to   better explanation.

Comment: @Armali it must be defined in i2c.h. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank a lot to share your answer.
i solved it.In help file of codevision in explain of I2C:

The prototypes for these functions are placed in the file i2c.h, located in the .\INC subdirectory. This file must be #include -d before using the functions.

These functions must be configured, by specifying the I/O port and bits used for communication through the I2C bus and the bit rate of the SCL clock.
This is accomplished in the Project|Configure|C Compiler|Libraries|I2C menu:
the Enable Bit-Banged I2C Support option must be activated
·    the I/O Port, SDA and SCL bits must be specified in Data Connection
·    the Bit Rate of the SCL signal must be set.